# How can I prevent arcing when plugging in high powered devices?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a portable induction stove whose plug arcs when I'm plugging it into the outlet, presumably because it has giant capacitors and lacks any sort of arc quenching circuitry. I'm worried that constant arcing when plugging and unplugging the device would cause carbon build up in the outlet, and eventually lead to a failure of some sort. Is there a way to fix this (e.g., with a switch of some sort), or am I overly worried about nothing?

Comment: What's the name plate rating of the oven?

Comment: Why do you think the stove has giant capacitors?

Comment: Where would the carbon to build up come from?

Comment: @vidarlo.... the air, the metal, etc. It's a common occurance where there's arcing.

Comment: agreed the carbon build up can amount to a problem.  How soon this will happen is dependent on how often you plug the oven in.  So this may be an issue in a month, a year, maybe not for a decade.

Comment: @isherwood I've seen molten metal due to arcing, but never carbon buildup. That includes carbon brushes.

Comment: @JACK 1800 watts.

Comment: @SteveSh Just a hypothesis of mine, since there's no reason for the huge current draw when first plugged in since the device isn't turned on.

Comment: @kitye - Not a bad hypothesis, but I don't think induction stoves/cook tops have such capacitors.  They're, simplistically, just coils of wire through which current is passed.  Could just be the control electronics powering up, which is not unusual.  Heck, I hear or see a spark even when I plug a USB charger or wall wort into an outlet.

Comment: Note I've never seen (loose) carbon buildup.  I have seen discolored and pitted male and female parts of plugs, which causes increased resistance which leads to overheating of the plug.

Comment: How about a switched socket? I'd be really scared by something that is sucking power, for any reason, when it's not switched on.

Comment: My US made UL rated phone charger generally do that when plugging them in.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you're overly worried about nothing. If in the USA and UL listed, then it's OK. Make an effort to plug in the oven quickly to extinguish the arc faster. Worse case, after a number of years, you'll have to replace the outlet/plug. Normal outlets go bad with continuous use and have to be replaced. The oven is a low current draw, 15/7.5 amps at 120//240 volts so you could add a switch to the outlet circuit but you'll still have the arcing in the switch so you won't solve the problem and you won't be able to inspect the contacts like you would be able to do with just plugging it in to an outlet.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I don't believe @kitye mentioned the product was UL listed. I don't think UL would underwrite an arcing piece of equipment. It will become a problem if he plugs into an AFCI circuit since that is what an arc fault protector is all about, and these are being installed in every house manufactured in some manner since the beginning of this century. Is it enough of an arc to burn up a receptacle? Probably not. Will it trip an AFCI Breaker? Definitely.

Answer (score 2):

### DON'T plug in with the device switched on!

That's just asking for arcing.

Now, many appliances are built that way - there is no switch, "plugging it in" is the switch. **These appliances are UL-Listed that way** which reflects the level of concern UL has with a socket live-switching 1500 watts.

### A quality socket costs $4.

Don't worry about it.

Also, if the arcing amounts to anything, you'll see direct evidence of that on the prongs on the plug.